# How to chain custom functions onto existing dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, chaining

I have a project where I would like to read a single csv file into a dataframe. I then wish to apply several different filters/transformations to the dataframe instance in multiple locations, without assigning the result to a new dataframe (ie want to get a returned value from the chained functions, then start again on the original dataframe).

For example:

```
data = pd.read_csv(...)

A: graphing_function(data.custom_function1(...).custom_function2(...)))

B: graphing_function(data.custom_function2(...).custom_function3(...)))
```

where the result from B does not depend on A. (ie the data variable is unmodified by the custom function calls).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please provide a minimal example (input and expected output)

Answer (score 1):

To do method chaining use [`DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html).

```
def add_one(df):
    return df + 1

def power(df, n):
    return df ** n

def multiply(df, c):
    return c * df

>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,4],[6,8],[2,5]], columns=list('AB'))
>>> df

   A  B
0  1  4
1  6  8
2  2  5

>>> res = (
      df.pipe(add_one)
        .pipe(power, n=2)
        .pipe(multiply, c=10)
)

>>> res

     A    B
0   40  250
1  490  810
2   90  360
```